# How to typecast from AbstractControl to FormGroup in template?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a component that takes FormGroup as @Input.

parentComponent:

```
parentGroup = fb.group({
  childGroup: fb.group({
     nestedControl: fb.control([])
  })
})
<app-my-component [formGroup]="myGroup">
```

Then in the child component I have:

```
@Input formGroup: FormGroup
<div *ngIf="formGroup.controls.childGroup.controls.nestedControl === true">
   some content
</div>
```

I get an error

```
error TS2339: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

I guess the child control does not know the structure of formGroup input.  How do I typecast AbstractControl to FormGroup within the template?  I guess I can make a function that casts in the .ts file and returns formGroup, but that seems cumbersome.  Any way to do it in the template? any other clever solutions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child component that error actually points to your nested group. Angular does not know that `childGroup` is a FormGroup. I don't see why you couldn't just send the child the nested FormGroup instead of the whole form. First of all your code becomes shorter in template as you don't need to traverse downwards, secondly, that error gets fixed as you can type that `childGroup` is a FormGroup :)

parent:

```html
<app-my-component [formGroup]="myGroup.get('childGroup')">
```

and child:

```html
@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

<div *ngIf="formGroup.get('nestedControl') === true">
   some content
</div>
```

Notice I also used `get`. I prefer that myself :)

EDIT: If you need to pass the parent formgroup, you can access nested propertied just like we use in JS objects, i.e using `.`:

```html
<div *ngIf="formGroup.get('childGroup.nestedControl').value === true">
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply.  The issue is that there are multiple child FormGroup objects that  I need to access.  It seems dirty to pass each of them individually.

Comment: check update, should work for one nested formgroup like that.

Comment: if you are out of options of even deeper nesting, in reactive forms is the only place where I resort to using `$any(...)` in template, so AVOID that if you can, but if you have really deeply nested formgroups, then... use that.

Comment: oh that's awesome, it works!! Thanks so much.

Comment: yw, glad I could help! :)

Comment: @AT82, in Angular in strict mode you can not pass as `@Input formGroup:FormGroup` a `form.get('childGroup')`. you need declare the variable formGroup:FormGroup and use a setter in input `@Input('formGroup') set _(value){this.formGroup=value as FormGroup)`

Comment: @Eliseo, ok, thanks. Well I use strict mode myself and haven't experienced that, but good to know!